# php map digit to string

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program in php which first prompts a user for a string. once they enter a string it is supposed to give the equivalent digits if it were on a phone. eg `ABC(2)` , `DEF(3)` , `GHI(4)` , `JKL(5)` , `MNO(6)` , `PQRS(7)` , `TUV(8)` , `WXYZ(9)`.
Im using a for loop and nested if statements but i am not getting the correct output. Am I going about this the right way? my code is below

```
<?php

$str = $_POST['usersString'];

$len = strlen($str);

for($i=0; $i<$len-1; $i++){
    if($i="a" || $i="b" || $i="c"){
        echo "1";
    }

    if($i="d" || $i="e" || $i="f"){
        echo "2";
    }

    if($i="g" || $i="h" || $i="i"){
        echo "3";
    }
}    

?>
<form action="task17.php" method="POST">
Enter a string <input type="text" name="usersString" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
```

Comment: you have checked the for loop count against a string. it should be your string's particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = $_POST['usersString'];

$len = strlen($str);

for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){

   if($str[$i]=="a" || $str[$i]=="b" || $str[$i]=="c"){
    echo "1";

   }else if($str[$i]=="d" || $str[$i]=="e" || $str[$i]=="f"){
    echo "2";

   }else if($str[$i]=="g" || $str[$i]=="h" || $str[$i]=="i"){
    echo "3";
   }
}    

?>
```

your condition is wrong $i="a"
It should be $str[$i]=="a"

Comment: +1 for beating me to the first point about the offset.  Still contains the issue with excluding the last character though.  I'd modify it to exclude the `-1` in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

`$i` isn't going to be a letter in your loop, it's going to be an integer.  What you want is to use `$i` as the offset of `$str` like `$str[$i]`.  So with 'abc' `$str[0]` will be 'a'.

I would personally use an array for this to store the values:

```
$len = strlen($str);
$array = [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 2, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 2 ];
// and so on...

for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
  echo $array[ $str[$i] ];
}
```

Note that I also used `$i<$len` rather than `$i<$len-1`.  I don't think you want to use less than with -1.  This would lead you to exclude the last character.

Comment: I didn't check the answer has already been posted. I got delayed due to the formatting issue i faced when writing answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **$str[$i]** instead of **$i** in your **If conditions** like

   `if($str[$i]=="a" || $str[$i]=="b" || $str[$i]=="c"){
       echo "1";
      }`
2. change your for loop to

   ```
   for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
   {   
   }
   ```

Comment: Unless you're adding to an answer, what's the point of posting the same stuff?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "ADFJ";
$digitArr = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz');
$strlne= strlen($str);
$digCount = count($digitArr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $strlne; $i++) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < $digCount) {
        if (stripos($digitArr[$j], $str[$i]) !== false) {
            $output[] = $j+1;
            break;
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
print_r($output);
```